# ProgressDialog froze when a table is beeing populated with big amount of data

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

You shall never work with UI stuff outside the UI thread (main thread). But what to do in this case:

Run a new thread to retrieve a huge load of data. Meanwhile, show a ProgressDialog indicating the work. When the data is retrieved, invoke the main thread and populate the table. When populating the table with the huge load of data, the ProgressDialog is "frozen" for some seconds (since the UI thread is busy with populating the table).

Is there any way to make the ProgressDialog not to "freeze" while the table is beeing populated?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity  {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private TableLayout tableLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tableLayout = (TableLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.myTable);

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final List<Data> data = fetchBigDataFromInternet();
                MyActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tableLayout.removeAllViews();
                        for(Data d : data) { // This makes the progressDialog to freeze
                            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(MyActivity.this);
                            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                         }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
               ....
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is there any way to make the ProgressDialog not to "freeze"" yes dont do all your work on the UI thread. posting code of what you are doing also helps

Comment: Well, I am not doing the work in the UI thread. As I said, I start a new thread for retrieving much data, but when it is time to populate the table with the retrieevd data, I MUST do it in the UI thread since a table is a UI component.

Comment: you need to post code of what you are doing, otherwise its just a blind guess

Comment: @tyczj: I added some pseudo code above. Hope it helps. This question is more a theoretical one rather than a question for help.

Comment: by that code Martins answer is what you are looking for then

Comment: Use ListView instead ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way to make the dialog not to freeze, and thats using the "Lazy Load" technique, if the ammount of data you are populating is huge, break it in smaller parts, and populate accordingly, you need to implement a mechanism to know when new a new "piece" of the data has to be populated, this is very common in apps that have a huge amount of data, usually an "updating" or "refreshing" message is used...

Hope this helps..

Regards!